# how to view next image in imageview?

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

Hi I have images in grid view. when i click my grid view images, it's display in full screen. if i want view another image go back in grid view then select another image view in full screen. i feel it's hard one.. so i am trying to view images full screen view using to swipe....no idea how to create this method please guide me and give some nice codes also...

This is my working app screen shot:

[image]

[image]

source code: 1. ImageViewExample.java

```
public class ImageViewExample extends Activity {
      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      private Cursor imagecursor, actualimagecursor;
      private int image_column_index, actual_image_column_index;
      GridView imagegrid;
      private int count;
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            init_phone_image_grid();
      }
      private void init_phone_image_grid() {
            String[] img = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
            imagecursor = managedQuery(
MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, img, null,
null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + "");
            image_column_index = imagecursor
.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
            count = imagecursor.getCount();
            imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
            imagegrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
            imagegrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v,int position, long id) {

            System.gc();
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            actualimagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj,
null, null, null);
                        actual_image_column_index = actualimagecursor
.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                        actualimagecursor.moveToPosition(position);
                        String i = actualimagecursor.getString(actual_image_column_index);
                        System.gc();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewImage.class);
                        intent.putExtra("filename", i);
                        startActivity(intent);
                  }
            });
      }


      public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private             Context mContext;
            public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
                  mContext = c;
            }
            public int getCount() {
                  return count;
            }
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                  return position;
            }
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                  return position;
            }
            public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
                  System.gc();
                  ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
                  if (convertView == null) {
                        imagecursor.moveToPosition(position);
                        int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
                        i.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""+ id));
                        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                        i.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(92, 92));
                  }
                  else {
                        i = (ImageView) convertView;
                  }
                  return i;
            }
      }
}
```

2. ViewImage.java

   ```
   public class ViewImage extends Activity {
   private String filename;
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       System.gc();
       Intent i = getIntent();
       Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
       BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       bfo.inSampleSize = 2;
       filename = extras.getString("filename");
       ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
       Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, bfo);
       iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
       setContentView(iv);
          }
        }
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After getting id of selected image, implement this..

**// this Class For Grid view images**

```
package com.thumbnailview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Activity_ThumbView extends Activity
{

    GridView gridview;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
            {

                Toast.makeText(Activity_ThumbView.this, "" + position, 2).show();
                id=parent.getPositionForView(v);

                Intent i=new Intent(Activity_ThumbView.this,Activity_ImageView.class);
                i.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

        Context context;



        public ImageAdapter(Context c ) 
        {
            context = c ;
        }
        public int getCount() {


            return mThumbIds.length;
        }


        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return null;
        }


        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return mThumbIds[position];
        }


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) 
            {  
                imageView = new ImageView(context);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(75, 75));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            }
            else 
            {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            return imageView;
        }

    }

            public static Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                    R.drawable.a,R.drawable.icon,
                    R.drawable.b, R.drawable.s,
                    R.drawable.c, R.drawable.r,
                    R.drawable.d, R.drawable.q,
                    R.drawable.e, R.drawable.p,
                    R.drawable.f, R.drawable.o,
                    R.drawable.g, R.drawable.n,
                    R.drawable.h, R.drawable.m,
                    R.drawable.i, R.drawable.l,
                    R.drawable.j, R.drawable.k,
                    R.drawable.t,R.drawable.y,
                    R.drawable.u,R.drawable.x,
                    R.drawable.v,R.drawable.s,
                    R.drawable.cd,R.drawable.z,
                    R.drawable.bc,R.drawable.ab
            };

}
```

// This Flip image Class

```
package com.thumbnailview;

import java.io.IOException;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class Activity_ImageView extends Activity
{
     ImageView thumb_imgview;
     ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
     Button b_wall;
     Button b_home;

    // Animation a,b;
     private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
     private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
     private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
     private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
     View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
     int j;

     WallpaperManager myWall;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.image);

         j=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");
         myWall = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        b_wall=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b_home=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

         thumb_imgview=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumb_txt_image);
        thumb_imgview.setImageResource(Activity_ThumbView.mThumbIds[j]);

         gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());

         b_wall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {



                try {

                    myWall.setResource(Activity_ThumbView.mThumbIds[j]);

                } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            }
        });
         b_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Activity_ImageView.this,Activity_ThumbView.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
        });


     }

    public class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener implements OnGestureListener 
    {
          public boolean onFling(MotionEvent m1, MotionEvent m2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
          {
            try
            {
                if (Math.abs(m1.getY() - m2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;

                if(m1.getX() - m2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) 
                {

                    if(Activity_ThumbView.mThumbIds.length>j)
                    {
                        j++;



                        thumb_imgview.setImageResource(Activity_ThumbView.mThumbIds[j]);

                    }


                } 

                else if (m2.getX() - m1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY)
                {

                    if(j>0)
                    {
                        j--;

                        thumb_imgview.setImageResource(Activity_ThumbView.mThumbIds[j]);

                    }


                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            return false;
        }
    }

             public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
             {
                 if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
                     return true;
                 else
                     return false;
             }
         }
```

Comment: if i click b_wall button force to close application logcat: indicate error what permission i have to give in this application....

Comment: Sry forgot this,Give permission in mainfiest. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>

Comment: thanks @Hasmukh it's working fine awesome....now i am clear in this concept......

Answer (score 2):

Implement **OnGestureListener** in ViewImage activity and capture swipe from user.

For displaying previous or next image, use cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Store all image filenames in array when you are populating into Gridview and then pass that array to another view from that array you can get all images instead of go back to gridview for selecting images..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is indeed like RajaReddy P said: create an array with the filenames/urls pass it to the ViewImage activity...

For the ViewImage activity I really would use the ViewPager! Really easy to implement and the swiping is handled for you!

More about viewpager:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html